# Create VLAN based Virtual Network Interfaces in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vlan

I've recently learned that MAC OS has the ability to turn the integrated NIC into a trunk port. The manner by which it does this is it creates a virtual NIC assigned to each VLAN that has been defined to flow across the trunk. The following website provides a walkthrough on how to set it up: [here](https://ogris.de/howtos/macosx-tagged-vlans.html).

I'd like to know if this is possible in Windows 10. The intent is to bridge virtual machines running in VMware Workstation on a laptop to separate virtual NICs each configured for different VLANs.  Each virtual NIC would then be bridged to a separate vmnic in VMware. The laptop would then be connected to a switch with a configured trunk port.

I've learned recently about Intel's Advanced Network Services feature [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005677/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html). But it doesn't appear to be supported in Windows 10 as shown on that website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Windows 10 if you download the intel ans drivers.
But only on intel NICs
You can see some info if you type this into Powershell (with ANS installed)

```powershell
get-help Add-IntelNetVLAN -detailed
```

- The syntax is like this, creates two virtual adapters, one for each vLan

  ```powershell
  add-intelnetvlan

  cmdlet Add-IntelNetVLAN at command pipeline position 1

    Supply values for the following parameters:
      ParentName[0]: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
      ParentName[1]:
          VLANID[0]: 109
          VLANID[1]: 117
          VLANID[2]:

    VLANID VLANName                                       ParentName
    ------ --------                                       ----------
    104    VLAN104                                        Intel(R) Ethernet 
    Connection (7) I219-LM

    107    VLAN107                                        Intel(R) Ethernet 
    Connection (7) I219-LM
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Realtek NIC adapters have an "Ethernet Diagnostic Utility" which works in Windows 10, similar to Intel's "Advanced Network Services VLANs". You can find it [here](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1306934-realtek-provides-nic-teaming-tagged-vlan-support-on-windows-10/), listed as "Diagnostic Program for Win7/Win8/Win10", along with drivers for supported Realtek NIC chipsets.
*(EDIT)* Or, **better still [from Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software)** - less chance of it being a trojan and more up to date.

Once installed, to create a virtual network adapter assigned to a VLAN:

1. Open the "Realtek Ethernet Diagnostic Utility".
2. Click on the Realtek card.
3. Click on VLAN.
4. Click the "Add" button.
5. Enter the desired VLAN ID and press Return.

A new Ethernet adapter will appear, and you can configure it as any physical adapter: assign an static IP, for example. Using the Realtek utility, you can easily modify the ID or MAC of the virtual adapters, or delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in windows 10.  You can in Windows Server with NIC Teaming.

Comment: This is half-true, as OpenVPN created a workaround for a vLAN adapter, with a limited feature set, that can be utilized to create vLANs for use outside of OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 Professional, you can use Hyper-V to create a virtual switch connected to you network adapter, then you can create a Virtual Machine in Hyper-V with a Virtual Network adapter to which ever Vlan you want to access on each. You can also have multiple Virtual switches in a VM to access different Vlans at the same time. So instead of running your VM in VMware you can create them and run them in Hyper-V.

Answer (score -2):

The TCP/IP Networking Stack in Windows doesn't natively support vLANs, however OpenVPN created a workaround that can be utilized to create *feature-limited* vLANs on Windows.

1. Download and install [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/)
2. Once installed, run `C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\bin\addtap.bat`
3. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `ncpa.cpl` → OK
4. Right-click on TAP adapter → *Properties*

   1. **Required:** *Configure* → *Advanced* → *Media Status* → *Always Connected*
   2. *Internet Protocol Version 4* → *General* → *Use the following IP address*

      - **Required:** *IP address* & *Subnet mask*
      - **Not Required:** *Default gateway*, *Preferred* / *Alternate DNS server* 
         <sup>*(set if using DHCP/DNS server for IP subnet)*</sup>

---

***Note:***

- *This is a feature-limited vLAN and not like vLANs created on BSD/Linux*
- *AFAIK, to support vLAN tagging [802.1q], you must use either:*

  - *NIC hardware supporting tagging* 
     *or*
  - *[Type 1](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/what-is-hypervisor-type-1-2) hypervisor ([Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/tlfs/tlfs))*

Comment: **If you're going to downvote an answer, please leave a comment**, as I'm unsure why this was downvoted since it's literally the one, and only, way to create a vLAN adapter in Windows without hardware support - the Windows IP stack doesn't support vLANs _(AFAIK, it would have to be completely re-coded to do so)_ and is why OpenVPN had to create the TAP adapter. To my knowledge, they are the only ones with a software solution that doesn't require hardware-specific ethernet adapters.

Comment: Where would you set the VLAN ID? What adapter would it use for communication?

Comment: @SteffenHeil vLAN IDs would have to be configured at the router level, as the TAP vLAN adapter doesn't support vLAN IDs. As mentioned in my previous comment and the last sentence in the answer, the Windows IP stack does not support vLANs, so the TAP vLAN adapter is feature-limited, but it is the only way to create a vLAN on Windows without specific NIC hardware support or a hypervisor.

Comment: But then this is not a vLAN.... It is an completely unconnected adapter.

Comment: @SteffenHeil As previously mentioned, it is a feature-limited vLAN that does not have the same functionality as vLANs in BSD/Linux or with hypervisors, due to the Windows IP stack not supporting vLANs, and can be used to route internal traffic on the host between VMs or to create a bridge between it and another adapter. If it wasn't a vLAN, how do you suppose OpenVPN works on Windows, or how can network communications occur across the vLAN if it's not a vLAN?

Comment: This question is not about some kind of virtual adapter. This is about VLANs. Your answer is not about VLANs at all. At least not in the terms of IEEE802.1Q, which this question is clearly about (see the original question, especially the place where the VLANs are connected to a trunk port).

Comment: @SteffenHeil The OP's question was about VM host vLANs communicating with VM clients _(e.g. the host routes traffic, not the switch)_ and the OP never specified the vLANs needed to meet 802.1q, nor that host vLANs needed to be tagged, only stating the laptop itself would be connected to a switch with a trunk port _(this implies port tagging is implemented, which doesn't require individual interface tags when done at the router/switch level)_; while I appreciate your feedback, everything in my answer is factually accurate _(I have added an annotation to my answer to address your feedback)_.

Comment: **It would be interesting to hear the reason why this is being downvoted; AFAIK, this is the _only_ solution to add a vLAN to Windows without NIC hardware that supports vLANs via its drivers.** _Downvoters:_ Where is the factual inaccuracy in this answer? Please share any other way to add a vLAN in Windows w/o a NIC that supports doing so via its drivers. Hyper-V can do so, but Hyper-V isn't available on Home versions of Windows, otherwise **the Windows IP stack _literally_ lacks support for vLANs, and this will never change because it would require the complete re-coding of the IP stack**.